# PowerShell x64 does not recognize Install-Module is not recognized as the name of the cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I know Install-Module is a PowerShell 5 or above feature.

I am running Windows 10 pro version 20H2 with OS-build:19042.746

I checked the version of PS using `$PSVersionTable`. The output is provided below.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.610
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.610
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Another thing that I found out while searching for the fix is that, The **PowerShell x86** version is **working fine** and there are no issues.

I can't run the Window Management Framework 5.1 because it was meant for other systems to upgrade the PowerShell. However, I am running the latest version.

Is there any fix for 64bit?

Comment: You need the Framework 5.1, it's goes hand in hand with one another. Even running PSv4, and installing Framework 5.1, `Install-Module` will work as it's part of the package that it's referencing.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala None of the Framework 5.1 installer are working. Can you provide exact installer that I need to run?

Comment: Hi, give this a shot https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616

Comment: Already tried but it's not working. As I mentioned it's for upgrading PowerShell from windows 7 or other distributions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't know if it was a bug or not. I just reinstalled the windows and problem got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I found is copying the `Modules` folder in `Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowershell` to `Program Files\WindowsPowershell` (64 bit folder). Somehow the modules got deleted from the 64 bit Powershell folder. I cannot pinpoint the exact reason but I suspect the culprit may be the [KB5001330](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5001330) update.

Answer (score 0):

Huh, I wonder if this is a bug?

> The PowerShell x86 version is working fine and there are no issues.

This comment doesn't make sense as `Install-Module` is part of the `PowerShellGet` module, which shouldn't care if you're running the x64 or x86 shell. Regardless, here's a few things you can try.

- You could [manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-packages/manual-download?view=powershell-7.1) download [`PowerShellGet`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerShellGet/2.2.5) ([`PackageManagement`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PackageManagement/1.4.7) is a dependancy). Related:

```
# check if PowerShellGet is available locally
Get-Module PowerShellGet -List

# check if PackageManagement is available locally
Get-Module PackageManagement -List
```

- Have you ran Windows Update? If not: run it, restart, repeat until there's nothing left.
- `.NET` should have been installed with the operating system - check if it was.

```
# Needs to be run in an Admin shell. Alternatively, us the gui in next point
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName NetFx* | Format-Table

# if not, you can add it by going typing 'windows feature' in the start menu and going to
# 'Turn Windows feature on or off'
```

Comment: Both commands return nothing when I type them in PowerShellx64 version. However, PowerShell x86 return the binary and script version. No, there are no updates pending. It's working fine on my laptop with same windows version.